# Cannot Add User to X-Pack (elasticsearch)

Tags: security, elasticsearch

Im trying to add a new superuser to x-pack.
But in /elasticsearch/bin there is no "x-pack" directory. Only x-pack-env, x-pack-security-env and x-pack-watcher-env.

If I try to install x-pack the following error is shown:
this distribution of Elasticsearch contains X-Pack by default

Im running elasticsearch in a docker-container

Answer (score 1):

Follow this docment to enable password for elastic and kibana default user:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/security-minimal-setup.html#security-create-builtin-users

Then you can use kibana user management and add a superuser to elasticsearch or you can use `security API` :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-put-user.html